# Rest Webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, glassfish

I am developing a file upload service and using `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition .getFilename`
but it gives the filename along with the complete path which fails creating the file.

If I change to use the `fileName` in debug mode it works.

How to get just the uploaded file name rather than the complete path?

I am using the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Try another browser :)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I changed to IE it works  but it does not on Google Chrome

Comment: It was @unwichtich that made the comment about the browser, not me ;-)  I only edited your question to add some tags.